# How do I send Ether using geth on Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, ether

I've mined Ether and it has gone into a wallet that I created using geth. When I look online, people say to use `eth.sendTransaction({from: 'address', to: 'address', value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})`, however I'm not sure how to use this command on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The line you mention comes from the JavaScript library web3.js. If you want to use geth you first need to sync it to the blockchain. For this do. the following:

1. Start `geth` from the windows console
2. wait about a minute, then start `geth attach` from a second windows console.
3. on the second console, enter `eth.syncing`. As long as you see numbers here, the sync is still in progress. When the sync is finished, you see `false`.

When the sync is finished enter `eth.sendTransaction(from, to, value)` to send Ether. Note that prior to using this line, you need to unlock your account using `personal.unlockAccount(address)`.

Comment: When I call `eth.sendTransaction` in that fashion, I get the following error:

"Error: invalid address
    at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at <anonymous>:1:1"

The syntax for sending a transaction looks like this:

    `eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.accounts[0], to:"0x005080F78567F8001115F1eee835DD0151BEA476", value: web3.toWei(1, "ether")})`